# Hide subcategories from showing in sidebar module

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

Opencart 2.3.02

How can I hide the subcategories from showing in the sidebar module? I have it on the left hand column. It shows up in the main top menu under main categories and thats fine but i want it hidden in the side menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Category` is one of default Opencart modules, you can edit its `tpl` file to achieve what you want, so open this file:

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/module/category.tpl
```

remove this section:

```
  <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
  <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
  <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="list-group-item active">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="list-group-item">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

If you are using different theme and still see subcategories, try to edit this file:

```
catalog/view/theme/YOUR-THEME/template/extension/module/category.tpl
```